# How to make a polygon with a hole

Tags: postgis

I'm using postgresSQL with postgis and I'm trying to create a polygon with a hole. I read a lot of users asking for something similar, but I can't do it for myself. My code is

`insert into distritos(nombre,geom) values ('Distrito6',ST_MakePolygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING((-15.66486 27.91996, -15.60610 27.91820, -15.60359 27.97169, -15.66586 27.97144,-15.66486 27.91996),(-15.65753 27.95894, -15.61610 27.95995, -15.61459 27.93157, -15.65477 27.27.93007,-15.65753 27.95894))',4258)));`

but it doesn't work. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Polygon has a double parenthesis at the start and end, and inner rings are delineated by using single pairs of parenthesis, between commas, ie, ),( whereas a Linestring only has one set of parenthesis at the beginning and end. You are actually using the syntax for a MultiLinestring, which is probably where your issue is. You can fix you query like this:

```
insert into distritos(nombre, geom) values
      ('Distrito6', ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((-15.66486 27.91996,
           -15.60610 27.91820, -15.60359 27.97169, -15.66586 27.97144,-15.66486 27.91996),
      (-15.65753 27.95894, -15.61610 27.95995, -15.61459 27.93157,
         -15.65477 27.93007,-15.65753 27.95894))',4258));
```

Also, you do not need to use ST_MakePolygon, as if you are using ST_GeomFromText, you can create the polygon directly by using POLYGON instead of LINESTRING in your example above. [ST_MakePolygon](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html) is probably more useful when you have arrays of Linestrings representing inner rings.

The  [Wikipedia WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)  article details this very clearly, with WKT and accompanying graphics.

`NOTE: You also have an error in you linestring, you have a repeated 27. in 27.27.93007.`